# Error: Undefined constant "STDIN" Laravel Backpack Devtools

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm using
PHP: 8.08
Laravel: 9.5.1
Backpack: ^5.0
"backpack/permissionmanager": ^6.0

I'm trying to create a Model with the CRUD with Devtools

Simple, just the id

When I save it an error pages show up saying:

`Error: Undefined constant "STDIN"`

And referencing the file (red color):

`App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfAdmin   line 66`

The table is created at Mysql

The Migration and the Model php files are created

But it stops (error) when trying to create the CRUD

I have tried using the yellow [Generate] button at /devtools/model but the same happens

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hmm that’s odd. Never seen that before. Can you do that again, and on the error page, click the Share button and copy the URL? That will give us the possibility to see the error stack, so more info.

Comment: Also, if the model is so simple and already generated, does the command-line work? If you do “php artisan backpack:build” it will try to generate CRUDs for all models, does that work?

Comment: Also, when did this start happening? Did DevTools ever work for you?

Comment: https://flareapp.io/share/47q21o35#F77

Comment: It works with php artisan backpack:build Perfectly

Comment: It was a project I finished in may and have reopened it to add new features. DevTools was working perfectly before in this project.

Comment: php artisan backpack:build is for creating all the CRUDs. What is the command to create a CRUD for only one model?

Comment: Can you make sure you `APP_ENV` is set to dev or something, not `production`?

Comment: Is set to "local"

Comment: Ok since neither I nor Pedro were able to reproduce this... it might be something about your dev environment. Perhaps a combination of software that we haven't tested or something. Can you please tell us your Operating System (eg MacOS Ventura), what you use for your localhost server (eg. Valet or Docker), what your server is (eg nginx or Apache)?